# How to view hbase data stored in hbase by nutch

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, nutch

I am using apache nutch to store data in hbase that is using hdfs as its file system. I want to know which documents it stored in hbase etc. How to read that data from hbase e.g. Some pdf is stored in hbase. I want to read it. how I will do it.

Please guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web pages and documents are stored as a row. If you know your document link, you can get it on hbase shell or other tool (hive pig etc.) Nutch stores URL as reverse URL.

E.g. "http://bar.foo.com:8983/to/index.html?a=b" becomes "com.foo.bar:8983:http/to/index.html?a=b".

Information about Hbase Shell http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase/Shell

Comment: Is there some tool to view hbase data on webserver e.g. apache

Comment: You can use HUE (http://gethue.com/) or HBASEExplorer (http://sourceforge.net/projects/hbaseexplorer/)